# Crystal Report: sub report Formating issue

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image: Incorrect Format] 
[image: Correct Format]
 i am using two sub report in same group section. i want exactly the second image format and i got the above format.when i place the 2nd sub report in the end of 1st report reports overlap .

Comment: First of all Why are you using two subreports for showing in this format. You should be able to handle this in SQL itelf right ?